# mongoose, nodejs - add reference of current schema object to the previous schema object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am using mongoose, nodejs with MVC architecture.

So, I have two collections crops and pesticides. I want a many to many relationship between these two collections.
For example, if I have 2 crops like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af1d1d54558fae1d0010bb4"),
    "nameOfCrop" : "Tomato",
    "imageOfCrop" : "tomatoimage",
    "soilType" : " almost all soil types except heavy clay",
    "waterNeeded" : "water once every two or three days",
    "tagCrop" : "Vegetables",
    "pesticideForCrop" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af1d1d54558fae1d0010bb5"),
    "nameOfCrop" : "Brinjal",
    "imageOfCrop" : "brinjalimage",
    "soilType" : "all types of soil varying from light sandy to heavy clay",
    "waterNeeded" : "Regularly irrigated",
    "tagCrop" : "Vegetables",
    "pesticideForCrop" : [ ]
}
```

and two pesticides like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af7d3e735d4222b78a93838"),
    "cropForPesticide" : [ ],
    "nameOfPesticide" : "pesticide8",
    "imageOfPesticide" : "p8image",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af7d49122b63e0824ed2d3d"),
    "cropForPesticide" : [ ],
    "nameOfPesticide" : "pesticide9",
    "imageOfPesticide" : "p9image",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

What I want is that tomato's pesticideForCrop key have object ids(suppose) of the pesticide pesticide8 and pesticide9 (meaning tomato can be treated with pesticide8 and pesticide9) and simultaneously I want a reference(_id) of tomato in the pesticide8's cropForPesticide key and pesticide9's cropForPesticide key.

I have a very vague approach in mind like firstly, I save a crop with the pesticideForCrop key being null at this point. Then I save a pesticide and while saving it, I can ask the user to select the crops which can be treated with that pesticide. I don't know how to code this. It would be nice if another feasible approach can be notified of or someone can point me in the right direction of how to code this.

Comment: you are going right... where you are getting stuck???

Comment: I want an approach to do the referencing like the way I explained in the above question itself or any other way. The problem is I dont know how t o code this. The google doesn;t have any answers on how to deal with many-to-many mongoose references. Can you point me to some sample code or similar issue?